# Has anybody used HumbleFinance to display Graphs / Charts

Tags: javascript, graph, plot, charts

I am using [Humble Finance](http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index) to display charts similar to Google Charts.

My sample data is

```
var jsonData = [
   {date:'August 19, 2010',open:100.01,high:104.06,low:95.96,close:100.34,volume:22088000},
   {date:'September 20, 2010',open:101.48,high:109.08,low:100.50,close:108.31,volume:11377000}
]
```

Inside Jquery Ready function I am using my data to load this as :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var priceData = [];
   for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
       priceData.push([i, jsonData[i].low]);
   }
}
```

I want to print the Dates in X axis labels by using

```
HumbleFinance.xTickFormatter = function (n) { 
     var date = jsonData[n].date;
     return date; 
}
```

But its not working, and it throws this error on FireBug:

```
jsonData[n] is undefined 
HumbleFinance.xTickFormatter = function (n) {
    var date = jsonData[n].date; 
    date = date.split(' '); 
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding , I am getting this Error 

Break on Error // In FireBug
jsonData[n] is undefined   



HumbleFinance.xTickFormatter = function (n) {

 var date = jsonData[n].date;
 date = date.split(' ');
 return date;
}

Comment: @Kiran i think humblefinance is no longer maintained and is instead using `Envision.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps jsonData is not in the scope of xTickerFormatter, and you need to store it in another local variable, similar to priceData?

Answer (score 0):

It's because 'n' is a float. Convert it to an integer using Math.floor before indexing the array.

```
        var index = Math.floor(n);
        var date = jsonData[index].date;
```